# Python image analysis - Check whether picture matches video frames

Tags: python, computer-vision, feature-detection

I have a problem, not so easy to solve i guess. In general, I have a database of frames from different videos and I want to find for a given picture (which is not necessarily one of the frames but from some same source video) the matching source video.
So lets say I have some videos and extracted frames each x seconds. The frames are stored in the db.
My guess would now be to loop over all video frames in the db and try to find matching features. So I would somehow have to find features in the source image and then try to find these in the frames stored in the db.
My question is how can I achieve this? The problem is that camera angle and vieweing distance can be quite different when the picture in question was not taken quite close to the time the frame was extracted previously.
Is this even feasible?
I'm working with Python and OpenCV.

Thanks and best regards

Comment: Is the image an exact copy of one of the video frames?

Comment: The image in question? No it is not. It can be from any time in the video. I suppose the most difficult situation is if the image in question was taken at t + x/2, where x is the step at which frames have been extracted from the video. So basically in the middle of two frame extraction times.